# Execute on every file in a subdirectory, then delete file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I need help creating a batch file that first runs a command on every file in every subdirectory, and then deletes the file that the command was just run on.

For example:

```
c:\temp\1\file.abc
c:\temp\2\file.abc
c:\temp\2\file2.abc

Would run:
execute_command.exe c:\temp\1\file.abc
del c:\temp\1\file.abc
execute_command.exe c:\temp\2\file.abc
del c:\temp\2\file.abc
execute_command.exe c:\temp\2\file2.abc
del c:\temp\2\file2.abc
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I figured out how to do it for a specified directory with "for /f %f in ('dir /b c:\temp\1') do  execute_command.exe c:\temp\1\" which is fine for a single directory, but I'm not sure how to do something similar for every subdirectory; I could get a listing of all the files using dir /a /s /b, but at point I'm stuck on how to use those to execute a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `C:\temp` folder in your example, you should be able to just do

```
for /r %i in (*.abc) do execute_command.exe %i && del %i
```

The `/r` switch says "recurse into every subdirectory of the current directory and run this `for` command", and the && lets you put multiple commands in the `do` clause.

You can also specify which folder to use as the base for the recursion, so you could do this from anywhere (not just `C:\temp`) and it would work:

```
for /r C:\temp %i in (*.abc) do execute_command.exe %i && del %i
```

As Joey says in the comment, you can replace the && with an & depending on whether you want to delete the file even if execute_command.exe returns an error.

Comment: Just use `&` if you really want to delete the file and ignore the return value of the command.